# how to sequentially iterate rows in Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-schema

I have a Spark DataFrame like this:

```
 +-------+------+-----+---------------+
 |Account|nature|value|           time|
 +-------+------+-----+---------------+
 |      a|     1|   50|10:05:37:293084|
 |      a|     1|   50|10:06:46:806510|
 |      a|     0|   50|11:19:42:951479|
 |      a|     1|   40|19:14:50:479055|
 |      a|     0|   50|16:56:17:251624|
 |      a|     1|   40|16:33:12:133861|
 |      a|     1|   20|17:33:01:385710|
 |      b|     0|   30|12:54:49:483725|
 |      b|     0|   40|19:23:25:845489|
 |      b|     1|   30|10:58:02:276576|
 |      b|     1|   40|12:18:27:161290|
 |      b|     0|   50|12:01:50:698592|
 |      b|     0|   50|08:45:53:894441|
 |      b|     0|   40|17:36:55:827330|
 |      b|     1|   50|17:18:41:728486|
 +-------+------+-----+---------------+
```

I want to compare **nature** column of one row to other rows with the same **Account** and **value**,I should look forward, and add new column named **Repeated**. The new column get **true** for both rows, if nature changed, from **1** to **0** or vise versa. For example, the above dataframe should look like this:

```
   +-------+------+-----+---------------+--------+
   |Account|nature|value|           time|Repeated|
   +-------+------+-----+---------------+--------+
   |      a|     1|   50|10:05:37:293084|   true |
   |      a|     1|   50|10:06:46:806510|    true|
   |      a|     0|   50|11:19:42:951479|   true |
   |      a|     0|   50|16:56:17:251624|   true |
   |      b|     0|   50|08:45:53:894441|   true |
   |      b|     0|   50|12:01:50:698592|   false|
   |      b|     1|   50|17:18:41:728486|   true |
   |      a|     1|   40|16:33:12:133861|   false|
   |      a|     1|   40|19:14:50:479055|   false|
   |      b|     1|   40|12:18:27:161290|    true|
   |      b|     0|   40|17:36:55:827330|   true |
   |      b|     0|   40|19:23:25:845489|   false|
   |      b|     1|   30|10:58:02:276576|    true|
   |      b|     0|   30|12:54:49:483725|   true |
   |      a|     1|   20|17:33:01:385710|   false|
   +-------+------+-----+---------------+--------+
```

My solution is that I have to do **group by** or window on **Account** and **value** columns; then in each group, compare **nature** of each row to **nature** of other rows and as a result of comperation, **Repeated** column become full.
I did this calculation with Spark Window functions. Like this:

```
windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("Account","value").orderBy("time")

df.withColumn("Repeated", coalesce(f.when(lead(df['nature']).over(windowSpec)!=df['nature'],lit(True)).otherwise(False))).show()
```

The result was like this which is not the result that I wanted:

```
 +-------+------+-----+---------------+--------+
 |Account|nature|value|           time|Repeated|
 +-------+------+-----+---------------+--------+
 |      a|     1|   50|10:05:37:293084|   false|
 |      a|     1|   50|10:06:46:806510|    true|
 |      a|     0|   50|11:19:42:951479|   false|
 |      a|     0|   50|16:56:17:251624|   false|
 |      b|     0|   50|08:45:53:894441|   false|
 |      b|     0|   50|12:01:50:698592|    true|
 |      b|     1|   50|17:18:41:728486|   false|
 |      a|     1|   40|16:33:12:133861|   false|
 |      a|     1|   40|19:14:50:479055|   false|
 |      b|     1|   40|12:18:27:161290|    true|
 |      b|     0|   40|17:36:55:827330|   false|
 |      b|     0|   40|19:23:25:845489|   false|
 |      b|     1|   30|10:58:02:276576|    true|
 |      b|     0|   30|12:54:49:483725|   false|
 |      a|     1|   20|17:33:01:385710|   false|
 +-------+------+-----+---------------+--------+
```

**UPDATE:**
To explain more, if we suppose the first Spark Dataframe is named "df",in the following, I write what exactly want to do in each group of "Account" and "value":

```
a = df.withColumn('repeated',lit(False))
for i in range(len(group)):
    j = i+1
for j in j<=len(group):
    if a.loc[i,'nature']!=a.loc[j,'nature'] and  a.loc[j,'repeated']==False:
             a.loc[i,'repeated'] = True
             a.loc[j,'repeated'] = True
```

Would you please guide me how to do that using Pyspark Window?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
Even though this way costs a lot,but it's ok.

```
  def check(part):
    df = part
    size = len(df)
    for i in range(size):
      if (df.loc[i,'repeated'] == True):
          continue
      else:
          for j in range((i+1),size):
            if (df.loc[i,'nature']!=df.loc[j,'nature']) & (df.loc[j,'repeated']==False):
                df.loc[j,'repeated'] = True
                df.loc[i,'repeated'] = True
                break
  return df

df.groupby("Account","value").applyInPandas(check, schema="Account string, nature int,value long,time string,repeated boolean").show()
```

**Update1**:
Another solution without any iterations.

```
def check(df):
   df = df.sort_values('verified_time')
   df['index'] = df.index
   df['IS_REPEATED'] = 0
   df1 = df.sort_values(['nature'],ascending=[True]).reset_index(drop=True)
   df2 = df.sort_values(['nature'],ascending=[False]).reset_index(drop=True)
   df1['IS_REPEATED']=df1['nature']^df2['nature']
   df3 = df1.sort_values(['index'],ascending=[True])
   df = df3.drop(['index'],axis=1)
   return df

df = df.groupby("account", "value").applyInPandas(gf.check2,schema=gf.get_schema('trx'))
```

**UPDATE2**:
Solution with **Spark window**:

```
def is_repeated_feature(df):
windowPartition = Window.partitionBy("account", "value", 'nature').orderBy('nature')
df_1 = df.withColumn('rank', F.row_number().over(windowPartition))
w = (Window
     .partitionBy('account', 'value')
     .orderBy('nature')
     .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing))
df_1 = df_1.withColumn("count_nature", F.count('nature').over(w))
df_1 = df_1.withColumn('sum_nature', F.sum('nature').over(w))
df_1 = df_1.select('*')

df_2 = df_1.withColumn('min_val',
                       when((df_1.sum_nature > (df_1.count_nature - df_1.sum_nature)),
                            (df_1.count_nature - df_1.sum_nature)).otherwise(df_1.sum_nature))
df_2 = df_2.withColumn('more_than_one', when(df_2.count_nature > 1, '1').otherwise('0'))
df_2 = df_2.withColumn('is_repeated',
                       when(((df_2.more_than_one == 1) & (df_2.count_nature > df_2.sum_nature) & (
                                   df_2.rank <= df_2.min_val)), '1')
                       .otherwise('0'))
return df_2
```

Answer (score 2):

You actually need to guarantee that the order you see in your dataframe is the actual order.  Can you do that?  You need a column to sequence that what happened did happen in that order.  Inserting new data into a dataframe doesn't guarantee it's order.

A window & Lag will allow you to look at the previous rows value and make the required adjustment.
FYI: I use coalesce here as if it's the first row there is no value for it to compare with. consider using the second parameter to coalesce as you see fit with what should happen with the first value in the account.)

If you need it look at [monotonically increasing function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id.html). It may help you to create the order by value that is required for us to deterministically look at this data.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lag 
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit 
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

spark.sql("create table nature (Account string,nature int, value int, order int)"); 
spark.sql("insert into nature values ('a', 1, 50,1), ('a', 1, 40,2),('a',0,50,3),('b',0,30,4),('b',0,40,5),('b',1,30,6),('b',1,40,7)")
windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("Account").orderBy("order")
nature = spark.table("nature");
nature.withColumn("Repeated", coalesce( lead(nature['nature']).over(windowSpec) != nature['nature'], lit(True)) ).show()
|Account|nature|value|order|Repeated|
+-------+------+-----+-----+--------+
|      b|     0|   30|    4|   false|
|      b|     0|   40|    5|    true|
|      b|     1|   30|    6|   false|
|      b|     1|   40|    7|    true|
|      a|     1|   50|    1|   false|
|      a|     1|   40|    2|    true|
|      a|     0|   50|    3|    true|
+-------+------+-----+-----+--------+
```

EDIT:
It's not clear from your description if I should look forward or backward.  I have changed my code to look forward a row as this is consistent with account 'B' in your output.  However it doesn't seem like the logic for Account 'A' is identical to the logic for 'B' in your sample output.  (Or I don't understand a subtly of starting on '1' instead of starting on '0'.)  If you want to look forward a row use `lead`, if you want to look back a row use `lag`.

Comment: Dear @Matt Andruff, thank you for your answer. I have one question, would you please guide me what the point of creating order column is?In fact, when **Repeated** column takes **true** that **nature** column change from one to zero or zero to one, for the same **Account** and **value** column value.

Comment: d the data in. so to get my data in the order that you specified I had to artificially correct it.  2 I need an order by field for my window.  This is another reason I had to add that field and why I discussed  monotonically increasing function in my answer

Comment: That's right. Thank you. Would you please use this point to your code example: **when Repeated column takes true that nature column change from one to zero or zero to one, for the same Account and value column value.**?

Comment: I think I've corrected the logic. but you should take another look at your sample output because it seems to work differently from Account A to Acconut B.  It seems there is something signficant about starting on '1' instead of '0'.

Comment: thank you for your update, but the output of your answer is not what that I want . I update my question, I should look forward and it is not any difference in starting "1" or "0", the logic of algorithm is the same. For example, (b,0,30) repeated with (b,1,30), which "0" convert to "1", so both rows get "true" for "Repeated" column. Another example is, (a,1,50) convert to (a,0,50), so both rows get "true" for "Repeated" column.

Comment: I do not understand what you want.  I do not feel you have described what you want. For the nature column I see a sequence of rows I see 1,1,0 having different values for A and B and your logic doesn't explain why they should have different results in different accounts.  Also you say compare this row to other rows <-- pural, did you intend this row should be compared to multiple rows?  Also you say "both rows" should be true but I'm not seeing that in your logic.  I hope we can clarify these points so I can help you.

Comment: **did you intend this row should be compared to multiple rows?** yes, but this comparation is in each group of "account" and "value". In fact, I need two **for** loop for every group, but it costs a lot of time.